# javascript for color not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, html

why color not appear by this code

```
function doFirst(){
  var x= document.getElementById('canvas');
  canvas=x.getContext('2d');
  var g=canvas.createLinearGradient(0,0,100,100);
  g.addColorStop(.0,"blue");
  g.addColorStop(1,"red");
  canvas.fillstyle=g;
  canvas.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
}
window.addEventListener("load", doFirst, false);
```

Comment: Check dimension for the canvas container in your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code, there should be `canvas.fillStyle` instead of `canvas.fillstyle`.

```js
function doFirst(){
  var x = document.getElementById('canvas');
  canvas = x.getContext('2d');
  var g = canvas.createLinearGradient(0,0,100,100);
  g.addColorStop(.0,"blue");
  g.addColorStop(1,"red");
  canvas.fillStyle = g;
  canvas.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
}

window.addEventListener("load", doFirst, false);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

it worked. now why this is not working:
`function doFirst(){
    var x = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas = x.getContext('2d');

```
canvas.shadowOffsetX = 4;
canvas.shadowOffsetY = 4;
canvas.shadowBlur = 6;
canvas.shadowColor='rgba(0,0,255,.5)';

canvas.font="bold 3px Tahoma";
canvas.textAlign="end";
canvas.fillText("ongwtfbbq",300,100);
```

}
window.addEventListener("load", doFirst, false);`